# MPLS header parsing

Tags: c, network-programming

I have to parse MPLS packets. I gathered some packet captures(pcap) of MPLS protocol. Some had 2 headers of MPLS protocol whereas some have just one header. How do I know when will a packet single MPLS header and when will it have 2 headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bottom-of-stack bit, to indicate one more label. Else the data is popped out of MPLS headers and given to next level engine to Handle (it will typically contain a L2 or L3/IP header), it is done while the programming that correct engine is associated.

Comment: Thanks @legend_007